# What happened to evolution-mapi in 16.04?

Tags: email, evolution, gmail, evolution-mapi

What happened to the `evolution-mapi` package in Ubuntu 16.04?

I've searched for the package but I can't find anything.

Will the mapi package be available again in the foreseeable future?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(*i'm also from austria! ;-)* )

i looked a little bit around, and found that [evolution-mapi](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution/MAPIProvider) was [deprecated](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evolution). so it won't come back to the [ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=evolution-mapi).

after reading a bit further, the [german wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_%28Software%29#Interoperabilit.C3.A4t_mit_Microsoft_Exchange) says evolution-mapi was integrated into evolution 2.26 and also the [english wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_%28software%29#Connecting_to_Microsoft_Exchange_Server) says [evolution-ews](https://github.com/GNOME/evolution-ews) is now recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for you answer.

Yesterday i've googled arround a bit and found the same answer as you.

Now i've installed evolution-ews on my brand new installation of ubuntu 16.04.
After that i configured the profile and started evolution.

But there is a bug after the first start and evolution will not display the new profile. After i have restarted ubuntu and startet evolution again the profile appeared.

But because i'm using Zentyal and no Exchange itself there is a problem in the servercommunication. The evolution-ews can purge the Serveraddresses, but after that evolution is not working with zentyal.

So i have to search again about that problem.

Nice greetings from Neusiedl am See Burgenland Austria to Somewhere in Austria. ;-)

Comment: 1) keep in mind: this is not a forum, so maybe someone will flag/remove this "answer"... -- 2) i use open standards and i'm luckily not stuck to exchange-servers... so i can't help you any further with this topic. -- 3) in your case maybe [Zentyal](https://forum.zentyal.org/) or directly [OpenChange](http://www.openchange.org/) would be the right place for some help. -- greetings from vienna **;-)**

Comment: interesting... im not sure what's going on with [OpenChange](http://www.openchange.org/) (the exchange server of zentyal) - development seems (at least) very slow - but the server, dedicated client(?) and anything else related is dropped from the [ubuntu repositories](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=OpenChange).

Comment: thank you for you comment. i have tried to install the last version of evolution and its addons from github. but the same problem here. now i will try to find out more about this by contacting openchange. if i will have a solution on this i will post this as an answer.

Comment: openchange (as well as evolution-mapi) is no longer maintained upstream unfortunately.