# Evolution, MS Exchange

Tags: email, evolution, ms-exchange

I can't find Evolution in Ubuntu software center anymore, was it obsolete and having been removed? How could I configure my MS Exchange type of email in existing Ubuntu applications if Evolution was not available ? 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Seems as it has been replaced with evolution-ews according to this post [What happened to evolution-mapi in 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/776401/what-happened-to-evolution-mapi-in-16-04)

Instead you can run this command line in the terminal to install evolution-ews.

```
sudo apt install evolution-ews
```

Comment: Very useful ! Thanks I have successfully installed the evolution by following your advise.